# What happens to files that are mmv-ed by 2 different scripts run at the same time?

Tags: bash, concurrency, cron

let's say I have 2 different scripts that do a mmv on files from the same directory but to different target directories.
They are run at the same time (cron).

What happens to the files that match mmv's pattern ? Are they scattered in both target directories ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unpredictable result:

The first (there is always a first) would success,

The laters would fail -> generate some error report.

Answer (score 1):

This is a timing question. Who moves them first is the winner.

It makes a difference here if you move them to a directory within the same file system where just the entries are moved or across file systems, where the file is copied and then removed.